# how to get AWS Pre authentication Trigger on non-existing User

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When a non-existing user tries to login to cognito it sets response headers :

```
x-amzn-errormessage: User does not exist 
x-amzn-errortype: UserNotFoundException:
```

This is a security issue because the secure response would be something like `incorrect username or password`, I have tried to use AWS Cognito Pre authentication trigger for a lambda that resets the response headers but the lambda doesn't get triggered if the user does not exist. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my issue by creating an api gateway endpoint lambda that listens to the login request, if the login was successful then I allowed my client to do the authentication using the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` package. 
Here is my lambda :

```
    const UserManagement = require('./UserManagement'); 

    exports.handler = async (event) => {
      const { username, password } = JSON.parse(event.body);
      let body = '';
      let activeUser;
      try {
        const userManagement =  UserManagement.getInstance();
        activeUser = await userManagement.login(username, password);
        if (activeUser) {
          body = JSON.stringify({
            login: true
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in user management.', error);
        body = JSON.stringify({
          login: false
        });
      }
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body,
        headers: Object.assign({
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Authorization', 
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
        }, {}),
      };
    }
```

**my serverless configuration**

```
    provider:
    ...
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
          Resource: "*"
    functions:
       login:
        timeout: 600
        memorySize: 1600
        handler: functions/login.handler
        events:
          - http:
              path: /login
              method: post
              cors: true
```

for the **userManagement** check the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` documentation.